# Why relation divisibility is not relation partially ordered set on set Integer?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, integers

I try get it why relation divisibility is not relation partially ordered set.

$A=\{−2, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10\}$
with relation divisibility "|"

$R$ is relation divisibility | when $a,b,c \in Z : a = b \cdot c$

For relation partially ordered set must be relation:

- reflexive **(fulfil)** - everery number could have divisible with yourself
- antisymmetric **(fulfil)** - smaller number could have divisible with bigger, but not the otherway
- transitive **(not fulfil)** - why please?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3222978

Answer (score 3):

Divisibility is not antisymmetric on your $A$ because $-2\mid 2$ and $2\mid{-2}$.

Comment: Thank you. So antisymmetric is not fulfil and transitive is fulfil. Is that correct?

Comment: On notation: Some authors use a different def'n of poset (partially ordered set). In Forcing (a method in set theory) a poset relation  $\leq$ is defined to be symmetric and transitive. And $x\leq y\leq x$ need not imply $y=x$

Comment: Yes it's transitive but not antisymmetric. @user254665 It's unfortunate, and confusing, to use the symbol "$\le$" for a relation that is not reflexive, as the lower line implies to every mathematician alive "or equal". Where have you seen such a (bad) definition of "poset"?

Comment: @BrianO. in every article and book I've seen on forcing, including Kunen, Jech, Shelah, and in seminar & class at Univ. of Toronto.

Comment: @user254665 Nonsense. Kunen, 1st Ed 5th printing can be found [here](https://logic.wikischolars.columbia.edu/file/view/Kunen,+K.+%281980%29.+Set+Theory.pdf) [<-- link]. On p. 52 he defines a partial order, what many would call a preorder, to be a transitive and reflexive relation. I don't have Jech at hand but I know it very well and I don't believe you about his definition. Nobody defines a partial order as being *symmetric*, otherwise $<$ and $\le$ on our favorite number systems wouldn't be partial orders.

Comment: I  apologieze.  I meant to say REFLEXIVE not symmetric.On re-reading my first comment I noted my error. I hadn't realized that .

Comment: @user254665 Well, that's very different. OK I'll accept that :) Antisymmetry isn't generally required of forcing orderings. BTW, and surprisingly, I found Jech 3rd Millenium Ed too, [here](http://logic.wikischolars.columbia.edu/file/view/Jech%2C+T.+J.+%282003%29.+Set+Theory+%28The+3rd+millennium+ed.%29.pdf). On p.19 he defines a partial order as irreflexive & transitive, using the notation $<$, and then defines the non-strict, reflexive version $\le$. As I said, really nobody would use a symbol like $\le$ or $preceq$ for a relation that's *not* reflexive.